# Making rebar on cygwin, escript not found

Tags: makefile, cygwin, rebar, escript

I'm trying to make rebar on Cygwin using make command. I have rebar cloned from repository and I'm trying to make it. I'm getting this error message:

```
Sergey@PackardBell /cygdrive/c/Users/Sergey/Documents/Erlang/rebar
$ make
./bootstrap
/usr/bin/env: ‘escript’: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 127
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: may be you need to built it ? http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html